# What is the equivalent to the blood moon when in the depths?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I've run around the depths for quite a while (100%-ed the lightroots) and I realized... I never saw a blood moon in the depths.

The blood moon is essential because it causes enemies/ores to respawn for farming.

But if you stay in the depths, would that mean things never respawn/restock as long as you are in the depths? That you need to surface occasionally, wait for a blood moon, and then jump back down?

Or is there an equivalent event to the blood moon while you are in the depths?

Comment: 100%ing the lightroots doesn't take that long. Have you tried warping to the depths right before a blood moon happens?

Comment: The depths could be like shrines as far as blood moons are concerned (They delay it until a night when you are out of the depths)

Comment: No, but still, its a good few hours, 5-6 maybe if I was optimal; And it never did happen which by luck should have happened at some point. But yeah, maybe i'm just having a bad luck with it.

Comment: According to [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TOTKTearsTheKingdom/comments/142hr2n/does_anyone_know_if_the_depths_affect_the_blood/), blood moons will still trigger in the Depths with seemingly the same frequency as the surface

Comment: @pinckerman Reddit seems split, some comments say they got blood moons, but others say what I've experienced: No bloodmoons and its just the next night you are on the surface, boom, blood moon.

Comment: Sounds to me like shrine behavior...

Comment: @Fredy31 yeah that's why I'm not posting that as an answer, and I can't check that either

Comment: [Wayback machine to the rescue](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://old.reddit.com/r/TOTKTearsTheKingdom/comments/142hr2n/does_anyone_know_if_the_depths_affect_the_blood/*) @pinckerman
All comments were caught, too

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Blood Moon will ordinarily not appear in the Depths. I don't have too much information on this that's not anecdotal, so instead I want to focus on...

### How to force a Blood Moon in the Depths

The game uses a Blood Moon as, essentially, a hard reset in situations that exceed the devs' expectations of the load meant to be put on the Switch. So if you can force too many assets and too many render-heavy effects on screen, you cause an emergency Blood Moon<sup>1</sup>.

The easiest way to do this in the Depths is:

1. Find a layered wall (a wall with many breakable rock or ore pieces)
2. Equip a multi-shot bow (x5 for best results)
3. Go into Bullet Time
4. Load an arrow and attach an opal to it
5. Fire it off at the layered wall
6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 a few times before landing

The opals will cause a water spray effect. x5 for each arrow you shoot. All while breaking the pieces of the layered wall into smaller bits. And since it's in Bullet Time, when you land, the game tries to handle that all at once. Cue the Blood Moon.

For a video example see [this timestamped link](https://youtu.be/VRy7wICjZ_U?t=410).

---

<sup>1. Little did we know, unused Switch CPU and RAM are also Ganondorf-summoned enemies that respawn during the Blood Moon.</sup>

Comment: Note that these 'layered walls' you speak of never respawn...

Comment: @User I would expect them to respawn after a Blood Moon just like ore deposits, no? (Haven’t actually looked into it to confirm this)

Comment: I believe these walls stay permanently destroyed. Also, the ore deposits respawn on a different timer than blood moons.

Comment: @User23415 the respawn of an ore deposit is based on RNG, there's a random chance every minute to reset them

Comment: That sounds right.

Comment: I wasn't able to do it myself. I was, however, just able to do it 3 times in a row shooting aerocuda while falling from the upland zorana tower just under the big sphere. Using a mighty construct bow 31 attack+7 and normal arrows. Blood moon immediately triggers right after 5am. I had the blue cave lights active and the dragon was nearby as well. It seemed to happen when the game attempted to give me my resources from the kill